# high performance 'proper' c++ alternative to variable length array

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-explorer

I am writing a function which requires an array to be created at runtime. The array will be of small size so I am not worried about unsafe code, however, I want to write 'proper' code. As such I am considering three alternatives:

1. char array[len];
2. char array = new char(len);
3. std::vector array(len);

Using [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) to compare them with -O3.
The results were as such:

1. 12  instructions, 0  calls to new
2. 21  instructions, 1  call  to new
3. 118 instructions, 2+ calls to new

Am I missing an optimisation for std::vector<> or is the 'proper' c++ way slower or have I entirely missed a way of coding this?

edit: I forgot to delete the heap-allocated array

Test code:

code 1:

```
#include <string.h>

void populate_array(char* arr);
int compute_result(char* arr);

int str_to_arr(const char* str)
{
    auto len = strlen(str);
    char array[len];
    populate_array(array);
    return compute_result(array);
}
```

code 2:

```
#include <string.h>

void populate_array(char* arr);
int compute_result(char* arr);

int str_to_arr(const char* str)
{
    auto len = strlen(str);
    char* array = new char[len];
    populate_array(array);
    auto result = compute_result(array);
    delete[] array;
    return result;
}
```

code 3:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

void populate_array(std::vector<char> arr);
int compute_result(std::vector<char> arr);

int str_to_arr(const char* str)
{
    auto len = strlen(str);
    std::vector<char> array(len);
    populate_array(array);
    return compute_result(array);
}
```

Comment: The vector code also frees the memory which the other code does not do.

Comment: There's also `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Code 1 does not compile for me and it shouldn't. The value you pass as array size needs to be a `constexpr`, but here clearly it isn't.

Comment: Also `std::vector test` case should only be doing 1 heap allocation unless there is code we are not seeing that increases it's size.

Comment: Here's a few options: https://godbolt.org/z/Gv1oGM. Some errors in your code: The vector one copies the entire vector because you pass by value isn't comparable to the other ones (either pass by reference or pass the `data()` pointer). You should be doing `new char[len]` to allocate `len` bytes of chars. You have a memory leak in code 2 since you don't `delete[] array`.

Comment: `boost::container::small_vector`? Basically, choose an upper bound on `len` and then you can use an array (not VLA) of that size.

Comment: @fabian the code does compile for me, both on compiler explorer and locally. I am using CMake on Arch Linux which I believe is compiling with ```g++ -std=c++20 ...``` as well as basically every warning under the sun, and that works for me.

Comment: @Artyer Thank you so much for those suggestions. Two questions:
1. is there a reason you use ```static_cast<char*>(operator new(len))``` instead of ```new char[len]```?
2. Why is the use of alloca marked as POSIX only?

Comment: @EbonyAyers `alloca` is a POSIX function (which is similar to a VLA), not a standard C or C++ function. `operator new` is just a direct replacement for `malloc` that I would use in C code for a similar situation to this, but `new char[]` works just as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code, that may be leading you astray in the comparison.

1. `new char(len)` allocates a single char, initialized with the value `len`. You'd be after `new char[len]` to allocate `len` chars. There should be a matching `delete []`, too.
2. The `std::vector<char>` object is passed to `populate_array` by value, making a copy (and consequently not actually populating the array you want), and similarly for `compute_result`. These copies will engender new allocations. Passing by reference would be appropriate here.
3. Without using a custom allocator, `std::vector` will value-initialize all its elements. Effectively, it means that every element in this vector is set to zero. This is not performed by `new char[len]`.

VLAs are not part of C++, but may be provided as an extension. While in this instance, for small `len`, the compiler has the option of allocating the space for the array on the stack, they are probably best avoided because of their non-standard nature; even in C, they are not required to be supported.

Comment: Adding on to this comment, consider using
`std::vector<char> array;
array.reserve(len);`

Then later using `array.push_back(something)`.